# Mysql Revoke Privileges Not Affecting For Existed Connections

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have permission for creation and drop database option for a user and one of user connected with mysql and creating/droping db's and still connection exist with db through workbench. Now i am revoking drop option from user but its not working with already connected user. I want to revoke immediately from all user even if they are connected or not.

Comment: Disconnect user after changing options. User will reconnect with updated set of options.

Comment: Fancy-- Appreciate your work around but I want to do immediate on concern user without kill his process because it can be superuser of application and it can crash if kill its process.

Answer (score 0):

If you revoked the privileges via update statements on the privilege tables, make sure you execute this thereafter:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then you can force a disconnect by killing the user's threads. Do

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

and look for every `Id` where `User` column is the user you want to revoke the privileges from. Then kill the threads.

```
KILL <whatever Id you noticed from show processlist>;
```